# How to config ChromeView in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, google-chrome, android-studio

I downloaded chromeView Project from [chromeView](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview) in this project have guide for import it in eclipse but now android developers use Android Studio ... anyone use chromeView in android studio help me to import it in Android Studio please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is unmaintained. You can use [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) library instead of chromeview. 
Note: crosswalk lib might increase your apk size. 
(or)
You can cast WebChromeClient which comes with the default android libraries.

```
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: crosswalk increase my apk size to 40mb .
and using webview in android api < 19 is very poor because not using chromeView in it.
are u can build chromeView project in android studio?

Comment: Yes, it comes with all mobile browser support

Comment: can u help me build chromeview in android studio ? please